# angular material template mat-menu is empty

Tags: html, angular

I am not able to see the `Serial` option when `*ngIf="cards[i].vm_type === 'Container Provider'"` is returning `True` I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. [image: empty contents when clicking on Connect when vm.vm_type is Bhyve]

[image: contents when clicking on Connect when vm.vm_type is Container Provide]

```
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="(cards[i].state == 'stopped')" [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">Connect</button>
            <mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
              <button *ngIf="cards[i].vm_type === 'Bhyve'" mat-menu-item color="primary" [disabled]="(!cards[i].vnc || cards[i].state === 'stopped')" (click)="vnc(i)">VNC</button>
              <button *ngIf="cards[i].vm_type === 'Bhyve'" mat-menu-item color="primary" [disabled]="(cards[i].state === 'stopped')" (click)="serial(i)">Serial</button>
            </mat-menu>
            <mat-menu  #appMenu="matMenu">
              <button *ngIf="cards[i].vm_type === 'Container Provider'" mat-menu-item color="primary" [disabled]="(cards[i].state === 'stopped')" (click)="serial(i)">Serial</button>
            </mat-menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVM I figured it out

```
              <button *ngIf="cards[i].vm_type === 'Bhyve'" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="(cards[i].state == 'stopped')" [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">Connect</button>
            <mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
              <button  mat-menu-item color="primary" [disabled]="(!cards[i].vnc || cards[i].state === 'stopped')" (click)="vnc(i)">VNC</button>
              <button  mat-menu-item color="primary" [disabled]="(cards[i].state === 'stopped')" (click)="serial(i)">Serial</button>
            </mat-menu>
          <button *ngIf="cards[i].vm_type === 'Container Provider'" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="(cards[i].state == 'stopped')" [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu2">Connect</button>
            <mat-menu  #appMenu2="matMenu">
              <button mat-menu-item color="primary" [disabled]="(cards[i].state === 'stopped')" (click)="serial(i)">Serial</button>
            </mat-menu>
```